Has TeXworks done me dirty?
I spent many hours revising a file (using TeXworks for Windows) that came to me in a zip. (I forgot to extract the zip.)
I renamed the file and closed the editor. Now ... I can't find the file. The editor tells me it's a db file?
Surely the edited file exists somewhere? Right??
(If it doesn't, it would have been nice to have been warned, e.g. "Hey, the file hasn't really been saved.")
Edit: The db tables are empty. 'Saves' were in RAM. Nothing to be done.

Give everything a try to find the renamed file.

I think it's more Windows fault.  Try opening the file in the zip again, and Save As.  Look closely at the directory it's wanting to save to, and try to find that in your file system.

It's probably Windows' fault. Why it converted the tex file to a db file with empty tables, I'll probably never know.

I feel that this is not really a TeX related question, although you are working with TeXworks, but the same would probably happen if you open some other file from a zip and try to save it. So, this question might be off-topic here.

Please choose a title for your question which will help future users with the same problem find your question.

I made a test with texworks: when I saved a file in a zip under a new name it was stored in Appdata/local/Temp/somefolderwitharbitraryname/nameofthezip/ and I could retrieve it there later again. But I don't know how long windows keep the files, so you should hurry.

I have no idea about Windows, but in Linux, Texworks makes files like yourfilename.synctex.gz in the working directory. This is a gzip-compressed data file, but as the part "synctex" suggested, it is only for synchronizing the preview and the source editor. I am afraid that It is not useful to recover the text.
